# Tag counts way out of date

Tags: bug, tags

If you go look at the [main tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) *right now*, the count for the "new" [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag is off by **over 6000!** Tags aren't normalized, and this one is still out of date after a major re-tag.  It's the tenth-most used tag on Stack Overflow, and at the moment, it's not even shown on the first page.

Ooh: it gets even better. I just got a badge for the [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag, and I still have my [sqlserver](/questions/tagged/sqlserver) badge as well.

Comment: It's over 9000!

Answer (score 3):

There's a timing issue with the queries. Because tags are full text, the global replace happens so fast that a query to "count" the instances, counts none -- as they were all just replaced milliseconds ago by the previous query.

The daily tag normalization will pick it up.

Comment: Is the daily tag normalization activated now on superuser? As I'm still seeing lots of inconsistensies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this issue on SuperUser - most tags are off by a small amount but some tags (eg. `mac-os-x` or  `mac-osx` which have been replaced by a more popular `macosx` actually still show a days old number.

`mac-os-x` is showing as 11 instead of 0.
`mac-osx` is showing as 12 instead of 0.
`macosx` is showing as 3 instead of 28.

Is the daily tag normalization suppose to clean this up?

Comment: it's not running there because we seeded the db with a few hundred terms we thought would get use. If we ran it now, all those would be instantly erased. I'll run it by the weekend.